# PyGears How to make AND gate

Tags: pygears

Let's say I have two modules M1 and M2 and both of them are outputting 32 bits data. I would like to do logic AND for each bit. How to do it?
I have been looking into Library on GitHub but couldn't find module for AND operation.

I would like to do next:

```
X[0] = M1[0] && M2[0]
X[1] = M1[1] && M2[1]

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Code example of add_gate:

```python
@gear
async def and_gate(arg1, arg2) -> (Uint[32]):
    async with arg1 as a1:
        async with arg2 as a2:
            res = a1 & a2
            yield res

@alternative(and_gate)
@gear
async def and_gate_one_arg(args) -> (Uint[32]):
    async with args as (a1, a2):
            res = a1 & a2
            yield res


res_two = []
res_one = []
@gear
def consumer():
    arg1 = once(val=31, tout=Uint[32])
    arg2 = once(val=15, tout=Uint[32])
    args = once(val=(15, 31), tout=Tuple[Uint[32], Uint[32]])
    bits_and_two_args = and_gate(arg1, arg2)
    bits_and_one_arg = and_gate(args)
    collect(bits_and_two_args, result=res_two)
    collect(bits_and_one_arg, result=res_one)

consumer()
sim()
print(res_one)
print(res_two)
```

How it represents in GearBox:
[image]